# Windows Firewall will not start up

Tags: windows-7, firewall

The only backstory I have is that, prior to me noticing that firewall had stopped working, I moved a ton of things (namely Program Files & x86 and ProgramData) from my C drive to my D drive. I haven't had any other issues regarding this movement.

None-the-less, no matter what I do, windows firewall will not start. The only thing close to an antivirus that I have is Microsoft Security Essentials, which never turned firewall off, or at least not incorrectly. I've had no reports of any form of infection recently (or ever, really) so I'm fairly certain that's not the issue.

The Base Filtering Engine is running (same for its dependencies), the Firewall Authorization Driver is running/working. `HKLM/SYSTEM/CurrentControlSet/services/SharedAccess` has full permissions for `MpsSvc`.

I've done a fair bit of googling and come up with nothing. I've tried ESET's Service Repairer and it didn't work for me. I've tried microsoft's fix-it but all it tells me is that the issue is that "Firewall is not started" and it tries to start it (and fails).

---

**Starting the service via `services.msc:`**

> Windows could not start the Windows Firewall on Local Computer. For more information, review the System Event Log. If this is a non_Microsoft service, contact the service vendor, and refer to service-specific **error code 13.**

**Event Log:**

> The Windows Firewall service terminated with service-specific error The data is invalid..

```
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="Service Control Manager" Guid="{555908d1-a6d7-4695-8e1e-26931d2012f4}" EventSourceName="Service Control Manager" /> 
    <EventID Qualifiers="49152">7024</EventID> 
    <Version>0</Version> 
    <Level>2</Level> 
    <Task>0</Task> 
    <Opcode>0</Opcode> 
    <Keywords>0x8080000000000000</Keywords> 
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2016-02-07T04:33:43.695605200Z" /> 
    <EventRecordID>935435</EventRecordID> 
    <Correlation /> 
    <Execution ProcessID="688" ThreadID="7856" /> 
    <Channel>System</Channel> 
    <Computer>mycoputername</Computer> 
    <Security /> 
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data Name="param1">Windows Firewall</Data> 
    <Data Name="param2">%%13</Data> 
  </EventData>
</Event>
```

I've tried multiple commands:

```
winmgmt /verifyrepository
```

> WMI repository is consistent

```
Rundll32 setupapi,InstallHinfSection Ndi-Steelhead 132 %windir%\inf\netrass.inf
netsh advfirewall reset
```

> An error occurred while attempting to contact the  Windows Firewall service. Make sure that the service is running and try your request again.

```
sfc /scannow
```

> Beginning system scan.  This process will take some time.
>
> Beginning verification phase of system scan.
>   Verification 100% complete.
>
> Windows Resource Protection did not find any integrity violations.

Comment: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-security/the-windows-firewall-service-terminated-with/8f6e7846-e647-4673-ae26-fd4c38860df1 similar issue here see if this helps if it does I will post it as the answer for users with future issues can see it.

Comment: @NetworkKingPin Nope, didn't help. Grats to you for finding something I didn't, though.

Comment: It's an interesting issue man I hope we can get it figured out for sure.

Comment: http://damonjohns.com/2014/05/06/windows-7-firewall-service-will-not-start/ also this one which has a little of the same info but in a different way so if may contain a fix.

Comment: @NetworkKingPin Same error 13 when it tried to start the service.

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/mats/windows_firewall_diagnostic

Comment: @Moab The only issue it found was that the firewall wasn't running, which is exactly what my issue is. It tried to run it and failed (even said the fix status was "Not fixed").

Comment: This is usually caused by malware ind is hard to repair.